# Rails load stylesheet from wrong path in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, asset-pipeline

I have made a custom layout file which includes the following code in the header

```
= stylesheet_link_tag "label", media: 'all'
```

In development, this resolves to

```
<link href="/assets/label.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
```

Which is the correct path, however, in production, the same line of code gets me

```
<link href="/stylesheets/label.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
```

As you can see, in production it doesn't look under the /assets folder, and as a result I get

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/label.css"):
```

And my CSS fails to load.

Any advice?

Comment: It looks like you need to compile your assets. The end result of that is a static file. It does't look in the `assets/` path at all when running in production mode.

Comment: I tried to run heroku run rake assets:precompile -a APPNAME, but nothing happened

Comment: Not sure if you've followed all the guidelines in the [Heroku Rails 4 Asset Pipeline documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline) but it does provide a good checklist to try and isolate problems.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run in the terminal:

`rake assets:precompile`

Comment: I did, nothing happened

Comment: you also must specify the enviroment RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile, let me know

Comment: Turned out I had forgot to add the new CSS file to the list of files to be precompiled in the environment files